# SharePoint 2007 List as Datasource for SSRS 2005 - Query invalid and formating SharePoint Dates?

Tags: reporting-services, xml, caml, date-time, formatting

I have this XML query that pulls all entries and fields from a SharePoint list.

```
    <Query>
   <SoapAction>http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListItems</SoapAction>
   <Method Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" Name="GetListItems">
      <Parameters>
         <Parameter Name="listName">
            <DefaultValue>{XXXX-8857-4094-8F1E-F2F21E6BC596}</DefaultValue>
         </Parameter>
      </Parameters>
   </Method>
   <ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="True">*</ElementPath>
</Query>
```

**But if I attempt to add where clause as follows I get XMLDP query is invalid**

```
 <Query>
   <SoapAction>http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListItems</SoapAction>
   <Method Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" Name="GetListItems">
      <Parameters>
         <Parameter Name="listName">
            <DefaultValue>{XXXXX-8857-4094-8F1E-F2F21E6BC596}</DefaultValue>
         </Parameter>
<Parameter Name="query" Type="xml"'>
<DefaultValue>
  <Query>
    <Where>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="Title"/>
        <Value Type="Text">Cigna</Value>
      </Eq>
    </Where>
  </Query>
</DefaultValue>
</Parameter>
      </Parameters>
   </Method>
   <ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="True">*</ElementPath>
</Query>
```

**Also, as I build the report, I attempt to format sharepoint Dates from 
2013-04-11 01:01:01 to 4/11/2013 with no luck using properties format or =format**

***UPDATE: I'm also asking on MSDN:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/9039dcdf-12ab-4401-8142-0f91d41ec6ca***

Comment: If you want to do this ever use office and a copy of fiddler to record the transport. You can see how the XML works for office when getting list items or even retrieving a document properties or upload/download documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.  Query has to be in a parameter and must be called query.

My Dataset Query looks this:

```
    <Query>
   <SoapAction>http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListItems</SoapAction>
   <Method Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" Name="GetListItems">
      <Parameters>
         <Parameter Name="listName">
            <DefaultValue>{2C2C18D5-8857-4094-8F1E-F2F21E6BC596}</DefaultValue>
         </Parameter>
        <Parameter Name="query" Type="xml">
        </Parameter>
      </Parameters>
   </Method>
   <ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="True">*</ElementPath>
</Query>
```

My Parameter looks like this:

```
<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Title"/><Value Type="Text">Cigna</Value></Eq></Where></Query>
```

- No = or quote encapsulated.
- it matters that the parameter be called query.
- Title does not have ows_ prefix